# Android Studio Auto Complete duplicates

Tags: android, android-studio, code-completion

In Android Studio, autocomplete will duplicate the ending of the phrase if its already typed. For example, if I had a class that extended Activity, and then I wanted to change if to AppCompatActivity, I would start typing App... in front of Activity. After autocomplete, the result would be AppCompatActivityActvivity. Is there a way to use autocomplete so it doesn't duplicate what's already there.

Comment: It's not duplicating, it's simply autocompleting before the next token. Just ctrl-shift-right to highlight the text before enabling the autocomplete options to replace it.

Comment: Yea obviously it's not duplicating, meant replace. Highlighting will replace rest of line..

Comment: I've also found this annoying a bit, but I guess it's just too much for for it to also check if another part of the word is already contained after it and so on. Simply delete it and that's it :)

Comment: Yea that's what I've been doing. Oh well. It would be a very nice addition to code completion

Comment: My AS was actually doing this replace which is requested in the description above. Until I upgraded to Electric Eel. After this upgrade it started to misbehave as described above. As I am used to the proper behavior very much, I am very annoyed. I consider downgrading the the previous version of the AS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that what you really want is a "sentence replacing" instead of a "sentence adding" behavior, on the Android Studio Autocompletion.

That's very easy. Instead of pressing ENTER, as we all usually do, try with TAB.

**Note:**

- With ENTER it will add the code completion choice at the end.
- With TAB it will replace the old sentence with the new one selected
  on the autocomplete.

Comment: But for me, the ENTER was certainly working as TAB. Just until today update to Electric Eel... But thank you for this post. I will try to dig more before getting to downgrade AS to the previous version...

Answer (score 1):

If I want the "code completion replace" option to be the default one (by the "default", I mean confirming the auto completion with the ENTER key; rather than the TAB key) then I need to do this:

1. Go to Settings
2. Click Keymap
3. Find the "Choose Lookup Item Replace"
4. Change its keyboard shortcut to ENTER (by default it is TAB)

My problem was that the upgrade to Electric Eel changed the selected keymap from "My Customized" to "macOS" (BTW: This is NOT the only thing which this upgrade changed in my configuration)...